# Can there be 2 background images side by side on one row?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, background

I am trying to place 2 background images side by side (each in it's own container) on the same row in Bootstrap 3. [2 footer div backgrounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJSCi.jpg)

Whatever I do, the green div ends up on the next row. I am trying to use these 2 pieces next to each other as a footer, each holding text and social media logos that will stay in it's own div as screen gets smaller.

If I can't use 2 background images next to each other, can someone please give the code to do absolute positioning over . I don't think I can use clip-path because they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: post what you have tried so we can help

Answer (score 0):

- Give `display: inline-block;` and `display:left;` to the divs (image containers) and the images. Eventually set the `padding` and `margin` to `0`.
- You can use `span` instead of `div` for the image containers as well.

Good luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS resources -->

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JS resources -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .page-content {
                padding: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            footer {
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                background-color: blue;
            }

            .outer-container {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 10px solid blue;
            }

            .img-container,
            .img-container img {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section class="page-content">
            This is the page content
        </section>

        <footer>
            <div class="outer-container">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="left.png" alt="Left image" />
                </div>
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="right.png" alt="Right image" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for responding. I was able to finally answer my own question.

Yes, I can put 2 background images on the same row side-by-side. The issue appeared to be with the bootstrap gutters. So I created a no-gutter class to alleviate the space between the two divs and then I used a gutter class when the screen goes below 992px to add back in the gutters.

Amazing that you can be staring at the same screen for 2 days and then, BAM! Let that be a lesson to all you kiddies, take a break every now and then. Thanks again.

Comment: how did u do that? Please help me too. I want 2 background images side by side